# how to write a big block of html code within my controller in codeigniter so simply?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have 600 lines of HTML code which contains php code somewhere within it. And i want to print this HTML code if some condition getting true. so how can i fulfill this in my controller?
I've read about [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in php, but it's not working.
Is there any codeigniter or php function that can easily print HTML code?
Please help.

**Actually i am using Ajax, and i am posting HTML form using Ajax, and so as codeigniter's methodology my Ajax post request is redirecting to my controller, and this controller check this post data, and if post data is as requirement then i want to display some lines of HTML code without refreshing or reloading my view or we can say webpage. So how can i echoing my HTML code easily using controller without facing so many string manipulations and quotations?**

Comment: Why not to use [views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)?

Comment: HTML should be written in a `View`.

Comment: Make template(HTML) acccording to your conditions and pass it to the view accordingly, This is the right way to use Framework.

Comment: Thanx a lot..i got an idea...:)

Comment: Actually i am using Ajax, and i am posting HTML form using Ajax, and so as codeigniter's methodology my Ajax post request is redirecting to my controller, and this controller check this post data, and if post data is as requirement then i want to display some lines of HTML code without refreshing or reloading my view or we can say webpage. So how can i echoing my HTML code easily using controller without facing so many string manipulations and quotations?

Comment: No problem. Rendering view is not meaning that your page will be reloaded. CI just send its content to stdout the same way as `echo` do. And. You _should_ avoid echo in MVC architecture and use views instead.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter [Template Parser Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html)

blog_template

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{blog_title}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>{blog_heading}</h3>

{blog_entries}
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
            'blog_title' => 'My Blog Title',
            'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading'
            );

$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get view's html by setting the second parameter at true when loading a view.

**Ajax :**

```
var post_array =
    {
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
//We suppose a controller named Ajax
$.post(siteUrl + "/Ajax/my_function", post_array,
function(data)
{
   $('#content').text(data);
});
```

**Controller :**

```
public function my_function()
{
    $data["foo"] = $this->input->post("foo");

    //...some code here...

    echo $this->load_view("my_view", $data, true);
}
```